# Dynamically creating React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a new project with React. I have a component that defines several child components like this:

```
class TimeStepDisplayGraph extends React.Component {

  render () {
      return <div id={ this.props.id }>
             <TimeStepDisplayGraphNode class="graphNodeStyles"/>
             <TimeStepDisplayGraphNode class="graphNodeStyles"/>
             <TimeStepDisplayGraphNode class="graphNodeStyles"/>
             <TimeStepDisplayGraphNode class="graphNodeStyles"/>
             <TimeStepDisplayGraphNode class="graphNodeStyles"/>
             <TimeStepDisplayGraphNode class="graphNodeStyles"/>
             </div>;
    }
  }
```

Now ideally what I would like to do is not have the number of nodes created defined explicitly, but rather through a call like:

```
function createGraphNode() {
  return React.createElement( <TimeStepDisplayGraphNode class="graphNodeStyles"/>);
}
```

That I call x number of times. It seems like something really simple to do, and I'm sure I'll be kicking myself later for being so stupid, but at the moment I'm really at a loss for how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you know how many times you need to add that component then just use a loop or map function and return the element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. The simplest would be to simply create an array of size `n` and map over it, returning a React component for each one:

```
render () {
  const arr = new Array(6);
  return (
    <div id={ this.props.id }>
      {arr.map((ea, i) => {
        return <TimeStepDisplayGraphNode key={i} class="graphNodeStyles"/>
      }}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note that you need to add the `key` prop to each created node to uniquely identify it between renders. Using `i` is normally not ideal (because it does not *actually* uniquely identify which node is which) but in the absence of any other identifying data it will do.

This is a very common pattern in React - see [the official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can just put it in a function, like you are thinking, but you don't need the `React.createElement`. Something like this would suffice:

```
class TimeStepDisplayGraph extends React.Component {
  ...
  render () {
      return (
        <div id={ this.props.id }>
          {createGraphNode()}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
  ...
}

function createGraphNode() {
  return <TimeStepDisplayGraphNode class="graphNodeStyles"/>;
}
```

Or to add it `n` times, something like:

```
class TimeStepDisplayGraph extends React.Component {
  ...
  render () {
      return (
        <div id={ this.props.id }>
          {Array.from({ length: n }, createGraphNode)}
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
  ...
}

function createGraphNode(_, index) {
  return <TimeStepDisplayGraphNode key={index} class="graphNodeStyles"/>;
}
```

Is that what you had in mind?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, Muhammad is right.  This is how to use a loop to do what you're asking:

```
class outerComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      numberOfTimestamps: 100000  // (just kidding, make that smaller!)
    }
  }
  render () {
    let myTimestamps = []
    for (let i=0; i < this.state.numberOfTimestamps; i++) {
      myTimestamps.push(<TimeStepDisplayGraphNode class="graphNodeStyles"/>)
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {myTimestamps}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Edit: Changed to for loop rather than forEach.  Cannot forEach a number!

Comment: Numbers do not have `forEach` on them. This is not correct. (It's fine now that you edited it )